# reorganize tab bar items

Tags: iphone, uitabbaritem

I have an app with 5 tab bar items. I want to re-organize them, so I want to move the last position item to the 4th position.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes; you can ask your [`UITabController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for the `viewControllers` array.

Once you have it, move the items as you want, and set it back using `[yourUITabBarController setViewControllers:yourNewViewControllersArray]`.

Answer (score 0):

@houbysoft's answer is correct, just a few more details:

You can call: `@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *viewControllers` on your `UITabBarController`

Note that this will return you an `NSArray`. In order to work with this you need to create a mutable copy. Then, you can use `exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:` then pass this back in to `setViewControllers:` The whole thing might look like this:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[myTabBar viewControllers] mutableCopy];
[myArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:4 withObjectAtIndex:3];
[myTabBar setViewControllers:myArray];
```